# How do I make a Unity EditorWindow edit a currently existing object? Preferably an object not inheriting from MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started learning about how to make EditorWindows/CustomEditors, and I'm still a little unclear about what sort of things it is capable of. There are a hundred tutorials about how to make an EditorWindow/CustomEditor, and some tutorials about how to make them pretty. However, I'm interested purely in the capabilities it could provide.

### My Project

I save my player's data as a serializable class that does not inherit from anything. I take that class, use a binary formatter, then save the result to a file. I have a GameObject script that keeps a reference to the serializable class for use while the player is playing.

### My Goal

I want to have an editor window that displays the serialized class's values as read only strings. Then, I want to have input fields where I can set my own values, and a button that will update the values in the serializable class.

### Attempt 1

I made a CustomEditor for the parent GameObject. I tried searching for the field directly, but since it's a grandchild field, the compiler couldn't find it.

### Attempt 2

I tried making a variable in the parent object with a getter to just get the value in the serializable class. This works once, but never gets updated, so if one of the values naturally changes while the game is playing, then my CustomEditor doesn't show that.

### Attempt 3

I tried making my serializable class a SerializedProperty/SerializedObject, but neither work because my serializable class doesn't inherit from MonoBehaviour.

### Attempt 4

I tried making the variable in Attempt 2 a SerializedProperty, but since my variable has a getter, then it's not serializable and therefore cannot be a SerializedProperty.

### Bonus

The way that EditorWindows are talked about, it sounds like you should be able to do pretty much anything with them. I'm imagining that you could make and edit specific file types with them, like you do with the Animation/Animator windows and the Localization windows. I can imagine so many different tools that could be useful, but I just can't seem to find more in-depth, high level, and less introductory examples. Any you could point me to would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this kind of question is generally off-topic (speculating on options is an open-ended topic) but you might get what you want by inheriting from [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) instead of `MonoBehaviour`.  Another option you might have success with, and what I've done in the past to deal with the getter serialization issue, is to force the class to draw itself via some interface like `IDrawMyself`, and you would pass a reference to the UI panel, etc. to the class and it draws itself in that frame. Then updating the UI happens as part of the getter.

Comment: If you check out the [Model-view-viewmodel pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–viewmodel), this is the approach I took previously. The model is the class you're trying to display, the view is the UI that you want to populate. The viewmodel is a third class that you would create that does the data binding. For me, I had a `public GetterProperty{get;}` and then also a `public System.Event GetterPropertyChanged` that my viewmodel would subscribe to. In the get/set methods you can call `GetterPropertyChanged?.Invoke()` and any attached viewmodels get triggered. Lots of ways to do it.